# How can one Vijnana condition its subsequent Vijnana?

Tags: anatman

In Buddhism's Kshanabhangavada,a Vijnana perishes fully,before its subsequent Vijnana Arises.so how can it condition it?Buddhism says that a Vijnana need not be permanent to store karma or samskaras because one Vijnana skandha simply conditions another Vijnana skandha.how is this possible if there is a interval between them ?

Answer (score 2):

i already answered this question.

at least the Pali suttas never say vinnana is the condition for vinnana

you appear to be learning buddhism from the wrong sources